# persistent org-mode clock-in history

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, persistence

Is there a way to make the list of recently clocked-in tasks in org-mode persistent across Emacs restarts and (more importantly) closed buffers? It's annoying having to find the previous task just because I happened to exit a file.

Comment: `org-clock-default-task` is a marker. I guess I want a permanent marker.

Comment: This would indeed be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a little package [org-mru-clock](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/org-mru-clock) to solve this.

When I run `org-mru-clock-select-recent-task` or `org-mru-clock-in` it finds all recently-clocked-in tasks from org files and stores the top `org-mru-clock-how-many` in `org-history`; that takes about 5 seconds, so it doesn't do anything if `org-history` already has that many entries. This is nicer than saving to disk, since I have the org files version controlled, and the initial 5 second wait is acceptable.

It's compatible with [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), ido, selectrum or the built-in completion; my init.el has this:

```
(use-package org-mru-clock
  :ensure t
  :bind* (("<f8>" . org-mru-clock-in))
  :commands (org-mru-clock-in org-mru-clock-select-recent-task)
  :config
  ;; I use embark, this gives me some actions on tasks:
  (add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'org-mru-clock-embark-minibuffer-hook)
  (setq org-mru-clock-how-many 100))
```

The ivy interface also happens to make it really easy to switch quickly between recent tasks:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Org-Mode also includes this feature by default. You can set `org-clock-persist` to `'history` to save the clock entry history when closing emacs. Or set it to `t` to also save the running clock when Emacs is closed. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Clocking-Work-Time.html) or the emacs help on `org-clock-persist`.
For this to work you also have to run `(org-clock-persistence-insinuate)` in your init file.