# Can I use ido-mode for org-clock-select-task?

Tags: org-mode, ido, org-clock

Is there a way to use ido to select tasks from the `org-clock-select-task` list? Having to read through the list to find the right task and then look at the number makes me lose my flow :)

Comment: Since `org-clock-select-task` does not use a `completing-read` of any sort, there is not a way to connect it to `ido` without rolling your own version of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following snippet to select a recently clocked task with `ido`:

```lisp
(defun org-clock-in-select ()
  (interactive)
  (let (res)
    (dolist (i org-clock-history)
      (with-current-buffer
      (org-base-buffer (marker-buffer i))
    (org-with-wide-buffer
     (ignore-errors
       (goto-char (marker-position i))
       (push `(,(org-get-heading 'notags) . ,i) res)))))
    (let* ((l (reverse (mapcar 'car res)))
       (task (cdr (assoc (ido-completing-read "Recent Clocks: " l) res))))
      (when task
    (with-current-buffer
        (org-base-buffer (marker-buffer task))
      (org-with-wide-buffer
       (goto-char (marker-position task))
       (org-clock-in)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually expanded this into a package [org-mru-clock](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/org-mru-clock). This also [pre-fills the clock history](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19473/730)), and allows using [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) or ido, by setting `org-mru-clock-completing-read` to whichever completing-read-function you prefer (defaulting to the value of `completing-read-function`), for example: `(setq org-mru-clock-completing-read #'ivy-completing-read)`.